# Load/Modify/Save a GeoTIFF in C++

Tags: geotiff-tiff

I want to process raster data (DEMs) using various algorithms of my own design.  I want to load (e.g.) a GeoTIFF, run an algorithm against its data, and save the results to a new GeoTIFF.  I would prefer working in C or C++ since they're fast and I'm familiar with them.  What would be the best way to go about doing this?

Here's some toy pseudo-code showing the kind of thing I want to do:

```
geotiff src = new geotiff("source.tif");
geotiff dst = src.clone();

for (int y = 0; y < src.height; y++) {
    for (int x = 0; x < src.width; x++) {
        if ( 
             (x < src.width - 1) &&
             ( src.data[x][y]   != src.NODATA ) &&
             ( src.data[x+1][y] != src.NODATA )
           ) {
            dst.data[x][y] = src.data[x][y] - src.data[x+1][y];
        } else {
            dst.data[x][y] = dst.NODATA;
        }
    }
}

dst.write("output.tif");
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to check the [GDAL C](https://gdal.org/api/index.html#c-api) and the [GDAL C++](https://gdal.org/api/index.html#id3) API's. They provide useful tools to open, read and write raster data to a wide variety of supported raster formats. Make sure to check [this tutorial](https://gdal.org/tutorials/index.html#raster) to get started.